# Flex LineChart advanced horiztonal axis?

Tags: apache-flex, linechart

I want to make a line chart that allows the user to select a date range for the data. For example if the date range span is more than 1 month, I want to to have a bar that shows the months, also if the date range is around 30 days or less I want it to show the dates for each day as well. Something like that.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a [`DateTimeAxis`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/charts/DateTimeAxis.html), and setting the `labelUnits` property to "days" or "months" as appropriate.  The axis will then do all the hard work of grouping your data accordingly.

In your particular case, when the user makes a choice from the combo box, you should have a handler that computes how granular to make the x-axis based on the user's date selections.